# Fail to rich data for twitter card

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

I don’t know why twitter card doesn’t work at all since I have migrated to new server : https://twitter.com/flickshot_fr/status/1044619154156920833

Twitter validator results :

```
ERROR: Fetching the page failed because other errors.

Unable to render Card preview
```

Url tested for instance : https://flickshot.fr/en/article/flusha-officiellement-transfere-chez-cloud9/5ba78da4da07e

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

According to Twitter's [Cards troubleshooting post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-whitelisted-unable-to-render-or-no-image-what-to-do-next/62736) the most common cause of that issue is a misconfiguration with SSL.